# Flex - compare string without considering the accents

Tags: string, compare, diacritics, flex3

I have a compare routine ... but I need it to understand that when i search a "e" I also search for "é" or "è".

Is there an esay way to do that or do I really need to search and replace every accentued caractere before comparing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to search and replace for every character since they are entirely different and no language will be able to figure out which characters you want to replace with what.  Remember, programming languages don't speak english, they speak 010101 :)

Depending on the language you want to do this in, you may want to consider googling for a pre-existing library or plugin.